# Redirection From ASP.net to Angular 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

currently, I am authenticating logged in user in ASP.net code.

After authentication, I want to redirect that user to the angular project.

The problem I am facing is I can do both of these options to redirect

```
return Redirect(URL);
```

or

```
Response.Redirect(URL);
```

but I want to send authentication token to angular.
I am not allowed to send it in requestParam/Query String.

Is there any other way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Better to send the token in the response and make the redirection in angular when u recieve the response asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply.

That redirected page is opened in new tab.

I cannot access local storage or cookies of the page from which this is redirected.

 var jwtresponse = await client.PostAsync(Authurl+"/jwttoken", httpcontent);
if (jwtresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
 var token = jwtresponseString;
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
Response.Redirect(url);
}

This "url" is the angular project running on a different machine. 
to this redirection i want to pass authToken;